# at the end or in the end

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, american-english, british-english

She has been asking me to buy her a book for a long time. At the end, I bought her one.
Is this correct? Why can't I use “in the end”?

Comment: Why do you think you can’t? It sounds fine to me.

Comment: I have just written the English exam where I had to choose from this two. I don't quite know whether or not my answer was correct.

Comment: Start the sentence in upper case. There should be a period after ...long time. 'At the end' is OK, but is more pointed or narrower than 'in the end'.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So it means I can use In the end too, right?

Answer (score 1):

Let’s start with the easy part of definition of the idiom.

> In the end = after considering everything
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in-the-end)

But the question deserves a bit more analysis:

> At = used to show an exact position or particular place
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/at)

Hence “at the end” refers particularly to “the end”. But the end of her asking is not defined by the previous sentence, so the meaning remains unclear.

> In = during part or all of a period of time
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in?q=In)

So “in the end” refers to the period in which the buying ended and the book was bought. This phrase conveys the meaning correctly.

Comment: Thank you. now I understand it.

Comment: :) I am glad of that.